# Django static images receive 404 error in windows production

Tags: python, django, static, web-deployment, windows-server

I am trying to deploy a Django app on a Windows server. I am able to make the pages load and am using wgsi. I am also able to load pages with images when using runserver, just not when accessing via the webserver. I have DEBUG = False.

My settings.py looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL =  '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
STATIC_ROOT = "/assets/"
```

When I do collectstatic, my files are copied into the assets folder.

But, when served, I receive:
GET http://localhost:8000/static/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
.....
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

also define the media root and url in you settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Your link has a link to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/ which gave me some useful information. I'm closer, but not resolved. 

I used findstatic to find my static files.  
E:\project\project\static

I output the BASE_DIR to see where static files should be. On my desktop, it is at:
C:\Users\xx\Documents\project\project\project
And the server: E:\project\project

Dev application is one deeper. I tried to add (one less .parent)
PROD_BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

Comment: I added PROD_BASE_DIR to STATICFILES_DIRS but this did not help.

Comment: I also added your suggestion, and also tried using /assets/, instead of /media/ since that is where my static files were located. This did not seem to help either.